# How do you reclassify a single integer band raster to keep only the last digit for each cell value?

Tags: raster, numpy, gdal-calc

I need to reclassify a raster with values in the form xxxxx1, xxxxx2, or xxxxx3. Each digit of cells values encodes a categorical information (e.g. first digit is the land cover, second digit the climate, third digit a land-use policy, etc.). I am only interested in the last category, but in its current form I cannot perform analysis, so I want to reclassify the raster to retain only the last digit. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy expression can be used as `--calc` argument in `gdal_calc.py` command. To get only the last digit of cells values in the reclassified raster, it is possible to use the `mod` function of numpy, to perform a modulo operation between the raster values and 10: `--calc="mod(A, 10)"`.